# How to get main parent category id from category/subcategory

Tags: joomla-3.x, category, subcategories

I am getting one category id in code but it can be the id of either category or subcategory. And by the following code i am able to fetch the parent category chain.

```
$Jcategories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
$cat = $Jcategories->get($category->id);
print_r($cat->getParent()); //gives me all the parent details including the main category but it is under [_parent:protected] => JCategoryNode Object( ) so not able to access this.
```

Otherwise, I will have to write multiple queries to find parent of parent id.
Now, I want to know the main parent id of this category. Example the chain is -

SHOES

- Sports

  - Running
  - basketball
- Casual

  - Sneakers

here, if the `$category->id` is of `running(subcategory)` then I want it's main category i.e. SHOES . If the `$category->id` is of `Casual(category)` then also, I should get the main category SHOES.

Comment: Are you are using an e-commerce plugin, it would be helpful to know which one if so, and also what you are trying to achieve?